# Display/edit Sprout Form entry in front end

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutforms, frontend

Following [Sprout Forms -- How to link to individual entries on the front-end](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16218/sprout-forms-how-to-link-to-individual-entries-on-the-front-end) I found code

```
{% set formEntryId = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set entry = craft.sproutForms.getEntryById(formEntryId) %}
```

but it doesn't have any field data. Including `{{ dump(entry) }}` in my template shows `object(barrelstrength\sproutforms\elements\Entry)` with a lot of structure but no user entered values.

I was actually hoping to reuse my custom form templates (Sprout Forms > Settings > General > Default Form Templates) so it'll cycle through all the field templates like when the user filled in the form but I just want to show values if the form has already been submitted.

Comment: Are you sure your `entry` does not contain useful values? Sometimes they are just difficult to spot when you `dump` the object

Comment: For 1, I submitted my form with a unique value in a singleline field. After getEntryById and dumping entry I can't find that unique value anywhere. For 2, I'm also trying to front end view the entry using the same form templates used to create the empty form. Each fieldtype/input.html has `value="{{ value }}"` so I should see the value there, no?

Comment: I'm digging right into the Sprout Forms code to see what I might be missing. File controllers/EntriesController.php has `$entry = SproutForms::$app->entries->getEntryById($entryId);` and then a few lines later `Craft::$app->getContent()->populateElementContent($entry);` before they render the edit entry template. Do I need to find a way to do that in my template to view a Sprout Forms entry?

Comment: This function can be called via `{% do craft.app.getContent().populateElementContent(entry) %}` it could be they lazy load it for certain reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprout Forms improved support of this scenario in v3.0.0-beta.27. You can now use the `setEntry` variable to populate the Form Entry Model that you want to use in the Form Templates that you output using the `displayForm` tag. See the docs on [Editing Entries](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/entries.html#editing-entries) for more info.

#### Populate a Front-End form with existing data

```
{# Get an instance of the your Form #}
{% set form = craft.sproutForms.getForm('application') %}

{# Get an instance of the Entry you'll be allowing a user to edit #}
{% set entry = craft.sproutForms.getEntryById(123) %}

{# Set the `entry` variable so your Form Templates know how to populate the fields with existing values #}
{% do craft.sproutForms.setEntry(form, entry) %}

{# Output your form as usual #}
{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('application') }}
```

---

**Original Answer**

*I've looked into this and am considering this a bug. I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-forms/issues/131) on Github and will update my answer here when we have a fix in place.*